# Return values from certain position in matching array

Tags: jquery, arrays, filter, match, lookup

I'm looking to create a function that returns a value from a set of arrays based on a particular keyword that appears in the URL.

For example:

```
var URL = "https://blah.com/BCKM";
var indexCode = URL.split('/').pop();

var choices = [['BCKM', 'Beckham', '7'],['SCHO', 'Scholes', '18'],['YRKE', 'Yorke', '19'],['COLE', 'Cole', '9']]

**find "indexCode" in "choices" arrays, then return**

var name = **second item in array that matches BCKM**
var number = **third item in array that matches BCKM**

$(".name").html(name);
$(".number").html(number);
```

So if the URL is blah.com/BCKM, the script would look up the var "choices" and return the second and third values and insert them in 2 spans:

```
<span class="name">Beckham</span>
<span class="number">7</span>
```

I'd just like to know if this is possible, and if so, if I could be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Looks very confusing and impractical. Try `const result = choices.filter(sub => sub[0] === indexCode)` then `const name = result[1]` and `const number = result[2]`.

Comment: Thank you. I completely agree with you. I just wasn't initially sure what type of function to s to get the best result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all find child array index which have  desire code ( eg. `BCKM`). Based upon that find `Name` and `Number` from child array.

Example:

```js
var URL = "https://blah.com/BCKM";
var indexCode = URL.split('/').pop();

var choices = [
  ['BCKM', 'Beckham', '7'],
  ['SCHO', 'Scholes', '18'],
  ['YRKE', 'Yorke', '19'],
  ['COLE', 'Cole', '9']
];


function find(choices, code) {
  return choices.findIndex(row => row.indexOf(code) !== -1);
}

var ind = find(choices, indexCode); // get index

var name = choices[ind][1];
var number = choices[ind][2];

$(".name").html(name);
$(".number").html(number);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="name"></span> <br/>
<span class="number"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is EXACTLY what I was looking for! I do have a fairly basic grasp of jQuery but this had just stumped me a little!